# "Invalid face reference: linum" even load linum after make frame

Tags: faces, font-lock, term, linum-mode

I want to have line number at buffer, but when I use Emacs server, the Message buffer display the following error:

```
Invalid face reference: font-lock-comment-delimiter-face [2 times]
Invalid face reference: linum
Invalid face reference: font-lock-comment-face
Invalid face reference: font-lock-comment-delimiter-face
Invalid face reference: font-lock-comment-face
Invalid face reference: font-lock-comment-delimiter-face
Invalid face reference: font-lock-comment-face
```

So I found out linum is designed to use after frame is created. So I add such hook in my `.emacs` file

```
(defun my-turn-on-linum-mode (frame)
  "My function to turn on linum mode."
  (with-selected-frame frame
    (linum-mode 1))) 

(if (daemonp)
    (progn
      (add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'my-turn-on-linum-mode))
  (global-linum-mode 1)) ;;; if not daemon, just do it
```

Then if I start with `emacs --daemon` and open clients, it works fine for the first client I open, either graphic or terminal mode. It also works good no matter how many times when I open graphic frames. However, if I open client in terminal mode for the second time, the same error emergences. The error continues to show up if I open client in terminal mode further.

I'm really frustrated after 10 hours' digging. Maybe I should learn Lisp seriously? Any suggestions are appreciated!